# How to make subtle Camera movements?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, camera

Not a very specific question, I'm just looking for tips on making sweet subtle camera movements, the smooth kind that those RnD showreels have.

My camera game is horrible rn, It's the one thing holding back my work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, what are those RnD showreels you're talking about? Maybe link some example. If you want some noise in your camera movement you can use the modifiers in the Graph Editor but I'm not sure that what's you want

Comment: Please don't expect us to know what 'RnD showreels' are. Please illustrate with an example of what you mean, and how it contrasts with what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases it's not that exciting, it's just a very slow motion and extremely long render times.

I always change the left pane on the animation tab to *Graph Editor*.

[image]

After you key a couple of positions on your camera you get bezier handles that you can move and scale to affect the interpolation.  Or maybe setting them to linear makes more sense for some things.

[image]

Now, unfortunately the more things you are keying (Location, Rotation, Focal Length, etc) the bigger this hairball becomes, but for large sweeping motions this makes a lot of sense and provides good control.  In some cases you can even eliminate entire channels, I picked a motion that doesn't change over the z axis, so I right clicked the Z location and clicked *Clear Single Keyframes to delete that channel's keyframes and clean up the graph to the two channels you see.

[image]

My only other real piece of advice; to me it's hardest to start and end such things, so I'll usually key a much larger motion and then set my render boundaries to a portion that I think looks nice.

[image]